# How to remove bottom border of navigation bar with large title?

Tags: ios, swift

For navigation bar with small title, we could add these 2 lines in viewDidLoad to make the border disappear:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

However, when I do this for navigation bar with large title, i.e., when I set:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

The border does disappear, but the status bar also disappears:

[image]

What is the correct way to remove the bottom border for navigation bar with large title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For removing the bottom border you only need to set:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

---

With the below code you are affecting the background and that includes the status bar. Remove the line:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```